# Using json.load Keeps Resulting in Errors

Tags: python, json

When I run the following code:

```
filename = 'my_data.json'

import json
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

I keep getting the error below:

```
    JSONDecodeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-4-e76b2fcd5204> in <module>
          2 import json
          3 with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    ----> 4     data = json.load(f)
 
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)

        294         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
        295         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
    --> 296         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)

        346             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
        347             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
    --> 348         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
        349     if cls is None:
        350         cls = JSONDecoder

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)

        335 
        336         """
    --> 337         obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
        338         end = _w(s, end).end()
        339         if end != len(s):

/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py in raw_decode(self, s, idx)
        353             obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
        354         except StopIteration as err:
    --> 355             raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
        356         return obj, end

    JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any reason this would be the case? json.load(f) was working fine about one hour ago for me. Thank you for any help and insight.

Comment: The file doesn't contain valid JSON.

Comment: Right.  You'd better bring the file up into an editor and see what has happened to it.

Comment: It's getting an error on the first character of the file.  Check the first line of the file.  My guess is the file was written as UTF-8 w/ BOM.  `json.load` doesn't want to see it.  Use `with open(filename,encoding='utf-8-sig') as f:  data = json.load(f)`.

Comment: I ran the file through the command line and I tested the 'my_data.json' file with readline and it looked fine. I was also running the same exact code one hour ago and it was working ok.

Comment: I created a file encoded with a UTF-8 BOM and it failed with your error.  Check your file with a hex editor.

Comment: When I do print(f.readline()) it makes an output but json.load(f) does not work. Any reason why that would be?